# How to make Separate Process that always takes new Input inside loop in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I need to run a function inside while loop as a separate process that will always take a new input in every loop. I'm not sure what's the official term for that definition. I'm thinking about `std::thread` but I'm not sure whether it is the correct way to use thread. Example :

```
void Foo(int i){
    //.....  bunches of operations
}

int main(){
    int i = 0;
    std::thread th1;
    while(i < 5)  // exit flag example
    {
        i++; //incremented i
        th1 = std::thread(Foo, i);  //run the function as separated process that takes new value of i
        // .... other operations
    }
    th1.join();  //finish processing the thread
    return 0;
}
```

The above program doesn't work with `Aborted (core dumped)` and I think I got a memory leak because my C drive memory was drastically decreased.

**Update** : If I put the `join` inside the loop the program will work

```
while(i < 5)
    {
        i++; //incremented i
        th1 = std::thread(Foo, i);  //run the function as separated process that takes new value of i
        std::cout<<"test"<<std::endl;
        th1.join();  //finish processing the thread
    }
```

But I'm not sure whether the thread and the main process run at the same time, or it is just run like running the normal function. Anyone knows the right way to do it?

Comment: 1. while is infinite loop, you never end program
2. th1 = std::thread(Foo, i) creates new process in every iteration while you join just the last one in case you ever goes out of that while

Comment: @Angen updated, I actually have my own flag to determine when the loop will end. That's my question, then how to create separate process that takes incremented input and join properly?

Comment: Use a container to store all threads and `join` all threads after the loop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Concurrent queue or threadsafe queue is the thing that I'm looking for. Because I want the thread to keep taking new input inside loop and execute the function in the right order, I have to implement the `pop` and `push` queue operation.

Single thread program flow sample :

```
Foo(i, q)
    auto out = q.pop()
    print out

Queue q
While()
    i++
    q.push(i)
    Thread1(Foo, i, q) -> execute  // Using vector thread better
    // rest of operation
```

For explanation read this [tutorial](https://juanchopanzacpp.wordpress.com/2013/02/26/concurrent-queue-c11/) and for complete C++ sample with multiple threads refer to this [github code](https://github.com/juanchopanza/cppblog/tree/master/Concurrency/Queue)

Answer (score 1):

Use a container to store all threads and join all threads after the loop.

```
void Foo(int i){
    ..... // bunches of operations
}

int main(){
    int i = 0;
    std::vector<std::thread> th1;
    while(i < 5)  // exit flag example
    {
        i++; //incremented i
        th1.emplace_back(Foo, i);  //run the function as separated process that takes new value of i
        // .... other operations
    }
    for (auto &th : th1)
        th.join();  //finish processing the thread
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I got a strange result, the function is not executed in the right order. By printing the `i` inside the function, I got this order `1 5 3 2 4`

Comment: @gameone67 that's not strange. The functions are not executed in a order. They are executed in parallel at nearly the same time. You can't expect parallel threads to finish in the same order you started them. If you need the functions to be executed in a given order you can't use parallel threads.

Comment: @gameone67 The threads are managed by the operating system, e.g. it's possible that the first thread is started on a busy CPU core while the second thread is started on a free CPU core. In that case the second thread could be much faster then the first one.

Comment: I see, is there any way to execute the function in order using other method other than thread? Because I need it in the right order

Comment: @gameone67 then you have to call them sequentially. Don't use multithreading. It's not clear for me how you want to execute functions in parallel in a given order. That is a contradiction. Parallel (multithreading) means that they run at the same time without order.

Answer (score 0):

When you start a thread you must decide what to do when the thread finishes. There are two options:

1. you wait for it to finish (because you want a result for example)
2. you don't need to wait because you need no result from it an you don't need to start something only after it completed

In case 1 you need to call `.join()` to wait for it to finish and get the result. In case 2 you need to call `.detach()` to inform the C++ library that you will not need to way and thread resources can be freed automatically when the thread finishes.

You must choose one of those two options. If a thread object is destroyed and neither `.join` nor `.detach` has been called before on it then your program has an error.